# Galois theory in a different setting

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

Suppose that instead of wanting to express the roots of a polynomial equation with arithmetic operations and radicals we instead wanted expressed it with arithmetic operations and $\sin(x)$ ?

What (if anything) does Galois theory say about this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, when can the roots be expressed using arithmetical operations and sines of rational multiples of $\pi$: because $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ the question then boils down when can the roots be expressed in terms of roots of unity? By Kronecker-Weber, this is possible whenever the Galois extension is abelian.

Comment: No I meant that starting from some field of numbers instead of making radical extensions we take one of the elements in the field (call it $a$) and extend the field with $\sin(a)$. The question is then for which polynomial equations is there a sequence of such extensions such that the roots of the equation are in this field.

Comment: @Timotej: I would be very surprised if any of the numbers you get this way are algebraic due to results like the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) other than the ones expressible in terms of roots of unity. (I would also expect this to be very hard to prove.)